# How do I display a binary Image?

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

This is a raw  16-bit gray scale  binary image:

```
  0000 1111 1111 1000,  0000 1111 1111 1001, 0000 1111 1111 1002, 0000 1111 1111 1003
```

How do I display this Image (I do not want to do compression)?

**Update:**

The camera which is giving me this image has another option to get a 32 bit BMP. But I want to get a 16 bit Image. I do not want to loose accuracy so want to keep the size 16 bits per pixel.

Actually I am looking for some way for displaying this image (in 16 bit per pixel, gray-scale ), and save in 16 bpp.

Comment: Is the image 4X1, 2X2, or 1X4?

Comment: It is not possible to display 16 bits per pixel, because display adapters do not allow it. 8 Bits per pixel is generally more than the human eye can discern anyway, unless the gamma curve is not set optimally. What you really require is the optimal method of converting 16 bits per pixel to 8 bits per pixel, and that will depend very much on the characteristics of your camera.

Comment: Did any of the answers provided help you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open ended question.  The reason is you could use pseudocoloring if you wanted to maintain the 16 bits per pixel without losing any information.  You could lop off the least significant 8 bits of each pixel, and end up with an 8 bit grayscale.

There are other methods as well, depeneds on what you want!!!

In all cases, if you want to end up with grayscale simply for display, it makes NO sense keeping more than 8 bits per pixel as the human eye cant distinguish more gray levels than that.  Pseudocoloring allows you to display the added pixel information by adding another color component (or more) allowing the total displayable depth to go beyond 256 levels, as your eye now can distinguish from more colors.

IR systems (prior to pseudocolored systems) were traditionally displayed in green scale instead of grayscale as the human eye is most sensitive to levels of green.

Again, all depends on what you want to accomplish!

Comment: pl see update: I just need to display image in 16 bpp and in gray scale and save this. How do I do this?